# Django- Stand alone script is not in Django environment even with $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a script in my django project as a stand alone. I am using Django 1.6, this is a development server so no uwsgi is used, and I am running in a python virtual server. The virtual environment seems good to me because I can run python runserver 0.0.0.0:9000 with no issues.

Here is my environment set up:

```
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_server $ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bot_server.settings.local
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_server $ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
bot_server.settings.local
```

Here is the my script:

```
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_server/bot_data $ cat req.py
import sys
import os
import datetime
import base64
import json
from generators import thread_generator
from do_request import do_request
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "bot_server.settings.local"

from .models import User, ThreadVault
```

Here is the output from running:

```
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_server/bot_data $ python req.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "req.py", line 10, in <module>
    from bot_data.models import User, ThreadVault
ImportError: No module named bot_data.models
(bot)one@chat-dash /home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_server/bot_data $
```

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in `bot_data` and make sure there is no typo in `models.py`

Comment: Yes, there is a blank `__init__.py`. The `models.py` is good because I did a manage.py syncdb without any errors. Also, in the admin console page I was able to add data.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the script will run correctly if outside/parent of bot_data. I will need to figure out why it the path of bot_data/req.py takes it outside of the Django enviroment.